# Making a copy of a project breaks the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, compiling, overleaf, copy-paste

I made a copy of my latex project for version control purposes and it broke the bibliography in my compiled document. All the citations are question marks and the bibliography is not listed. Nothing is changed in the document except for the title used by overleaf (original project name - copy).

The original and the copy are using the same latex compiler and tex live version. I also tried downloading the zip of the project and reuploading it and got the same problem. The tex file and the bib file are in the same directory.

For now I am just going to store a download of this version and modify the original directly because I don't know what else to do.
If anyone knows what the issue is or what I could do please let me know. If there's other information I should give please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Did you make sure to run bibtex to process the `.bib` file, and then rerun latex?  It sounds like this step was omitted.  The necessary combination of steps is described in this question: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: @IsaacHowenstine hi. Only for additional information: This ocurrs to me, also in overleaf.

Comment: Ask the overleaf support, they can look at the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem in Overleaf and just solved it. For me the original project was using TeX Live version 2017 (Legacy), however these settings do not carry over when duplicating a project. Therefore the duplicate was using the default TeX Live version 2020. Changing this back to 2017 (Legacy) in the Menu -> Settings -> Tex Live version solved it.